# IntelliJ Ultimate runs Tomcat even when I alter its installation path

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I've been having a problem running a simple JSF web app where the managed bean won't display. I was wondering if it had anything to do with Tomcat. It was installed at c:\Program Files\Apache\apache-tomcat-6.0.53\

I changed it by adding an "x" to the beginning of the folder name (xapache-tomcat-6.0.53). When I ran the app, it still said it was deploying to Tomcat and brought up the browser.

What's happening there? Shouldn't it not run if the path has changed?

Comment: Maybe you have a different Tomcat instance configured in IntelliJ IDEA or you still have the copy of the previous installation?

Comment: Not sure how that works. But I just deleted my Tomcat installation and restarted the computer. Ran the app and Tomcat was started up with the following messages: Sep 11, 2017 12:58:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start 
(INFO: Starting tomcat server)
Sep 11, 2017 12:58:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
(INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29)